# Как изменить fingerprint браузера

Tags: c#, cefsharp, fingerprint

В программе используется CefSharp. Стоит задача менять fingerprint браузера.

Насколько мне удалось вникнуть в тему отпечатка браузера, я понял, что сам отпечаток образуется благодаря анализу ряда параметров, к примеру UserAgent, плагины браузера, разрешение экрана и т.д.

Можно [здесь](https://amiunique.org) посмотреть пример fingerprint и параметры, которые его образуют.

Но для меня остается открытым вопрос как эти данные можно подменять?

Например, как подменить разрешение экрана?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, для того, чтобы поменять fingerprint браузера, достаточно просто изменить одну из его составляющих. Наиболее простой вариант - изменение UserAgent. Пожалуй, единственная сложность - это то, что вы работаете с CEF.

В CefSharp есть такая штука, как CefSettings. А у нее, в свою очередь, есть поле CefSettings.UserAgent. Думаю, понятно, в какую сторону я клоню. Пример кода с англоязычного SO:

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

     CefSettings cfsettings=new CefSettings();
     cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
     Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);

     chromiumBrowser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/")
     {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,

     };


     this.Controls.Add(chromiumBrowser);

}
```

Comment: Со сменой юзерагента проблем нет. Меня инетересует как подменить "неизменяемые" параметры: разрешение экрана, набор плагинов, системные шрифты и т.п.